# Low level access to a disk in failure

Tags: hard-disk, lvm, sata

I have a SATA 2Tb HDD device probably damaged: smart doesn't work, etc.
The partitions were built with LVM2.
Is it possible, with a low level tool, to retrieve one logical volume (in my case /var) and to make a copy of the content ?
By extension, to retrieve a file (in my case located in /var/lib/libvirt/images/) ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a tough situation but there may be hope. In the past, I have used `gddrescue` to make a copy of the whole disk (and avoid making the problem worse by trying over and over), then used `testdisk` to try to recover the partitions.